# Formatting in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I wrote this tool that takes six inputs from the user and computes two outputs based on the Boolean network displayed in the image. I want the six input fields to be next to the Is in the picture and the outputs respectively. How can I do that?

I'm fairly new to HTML and CSS (and to JavaScript too, however I know Java, so the logic was the easy part).

```
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Logic Gates</title>
</head>

<body>

  <h1>Logic Gates</h1>

  <input type="number" id="num1" min="0" max="1"></br>
  <input type="number" id="num2" min="0" max="1"></br>
  <input type="number" id="num3" min="0" max="1"></br>
  <input type="number" id="num4" min="0" max="1"></br>
  <input type="number" id="num5" min="0" max="1"></br>
  <input type="number" id="num6" min="0" max="1">  <img src="stimulus3.png" alt="Boolean gate network" width="500" height="400"> </br>
  <button type="button" onclick="addNumAction()">
    GO
  </button>
  
  <div id="result1"></div>
  <div id="result2"></div>

  <script>
    function andFunc(n1, n2) {
      return n1 && n2;
    }
    function orFunc(n1, n2) {
      return n1 || n2;
    }
    function notFunc(n1) {
      return !!n1
    }
    function norFunc(n1, n2) {
      return n1 && n2;
    }
    function nandFunc(n1, n2) {
      return notFunc(andFunc(n1,n2));
    }

    function addNumAction() {
      var n1 = document.getElementById("num1").value;
      var n2 = document.getElementById("num2").value;
      var n3 = document.getElementById("num3").value;
      var n4 = document.getElementById("num4").value;
      var n5 = document.getElementById("num5").value;
      var n6 = document.getElementById("num6").value;
      var b1 = new Boolean("false");
      var b2 = new Boolean("false");
      var b3 = new Boolean("false");
      var b4 = new Boolean("false");
      var b5 = new Boolean("false");
      var b6 = new Boolean("false");
      if (n1 == "1") {b1 = true;} 
      if (n2 == "1") {b2 = true;} 
      if (n3 == "1") {b3 = true;} 
      if (n4 == "1") {b4 = true;} 
      if (n5 == "1") {b5 = true;} 
      if (n6 == "1") {b6 = true;} 
      console.log(orFunc(andFunc(b4, notFunc(nandFunc(b3, b5)), norFunc(b6,norFunc(b1,nandFunc(b3,b2))))));
      var o1 = orFunc(andFunc(b4, notFunc(nandFunc(b3, b5)), norFunc(b6,norFunc(b1,nandFunc(b3,b2)))));
      console.log(orFunc(andFunc(b6,nandFunc(b3,b5))));
      var o2 = orFunc(andFunc(b6,nandFunc(b3,b5)));
      document.getElementById('result1').innerHTML = o1;
      document.getElementById('result2').innerHTML = o2;
    }
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XqZdP.png)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I tried to clean up your JavaScript a little bit, I used comments to explain what I did.

To place the elements side-by-side, first we had to group them together, then I applied the [`display: flex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox) declaration to their parent and the [`gap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/gap) property was for the space between the groups.

The image I used in an arrow svg that I converted to a base64 string

```js
// I used arrow functions to shorten the syntax also because we can omit the return value
const andFunc = (n1, n2) => n1 && n2;
const orFunc = (n1, n2) => n1 || n2;
const notFunc = n1 => !n1; // Using two exclamaiton marks (!) will not negate the value, rather it would convert it to a Boolean value of the value. Only one exclamation mark (!) will do
const norFunc = (n1, n2) => notFunc(orFunc(n1, n2));
const nandFunc = (n1, n2) => notFunc(andFunc(n1, n2));

const result1 = document.getElementById('result1');
const result2 = document.getElementById('result2');
const inputs = [...document.querySelectorAll('input')]; // Select all the inputs

function addNumAction() {
  const values = inputs.map(({ value }) => value == 1); // Here, we check the value of all the inputs.
  // The array is obviously zero-indexed so the first input's value will be in values[0]
  
  // This is the function derived from the image you linked
  result1.innerText = orFunc(andFunc(values[3], andFunc(values[2], values[4])), norFunc(values[0], nandFunc(values[1], values[2])));
  result2.innerText = orFunc(andFunc(values[3], andFunc(values[2], values[4])), andFunc(nandFunc(values[2], values[4]), values[5]));
}

// I'll advise you use addEventListener rather than inline events (onclick)
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', addNumAction);
```

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  gap: 0 1rem; /*Space between the group of elements*/
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.wrapper img {
  width: 2.75rem; /*Set the width of the arrow*/
}
```

```html
<h1>Logic Gates</h1>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="inputs">
    <input type="number" id="num1" min="0" max="1"><br/>
    <input type="number" id="num2" min="0" max="1"><br/>
    <input type="number" id="num3" min="0" max="1"><br/>
    <input type="number" id="num4" min="0" max="1"><br/>
    <input type="number" id="num5" min="0" max="1"><br/>
    <input type="number" id="num6" min="0" max="1">
  </div>
  <img src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,IDxzdmcgeG1sbnM9Imh0dHA6Ly93d3cudzMub3JnLzIwMDAvc3ZnIiBjbGFzcz0iaC02IHctNiIgZmlsbD0ibm9uZSIgdmlld0JveD0iMCAwIDI0IDI0IiBzdHJva2U9ImN1cnJlbnRDb2xvciI+CiAgPHBhdGggc3Ryb2tlLWxpbmVjYXA9InJvdW5kIiBzdHJva2UtbGluZWpvaW49InJvdW5kIiBzdHJva2Utd2lkdGg9IjIiIGQ9Ik0xNCA1bDcgN20wIDBsLTcgN203LTdIMyIgLz4KPC9zdmc+"
    alt="Boolean gate network">
  <div class="output">
    <div id="result1"></div>
    <div id="result2"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<button type="button">GO</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally I would advise against using position absolute and aligning things to the pixel, but this is one of those rare cases where it is warranted.

Group your inputs and outputs using a `div`, get rid of the `<br>` tag which should never be used for styling and is absolutely never `</br>`

Use [relative and absolute positioning](https://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/) or padding to align your elements as required

```js
function andFunc(n1, n2) {
  return n1 && n2;
}

function orFunc(n1, n2) {
  return n1 || n2;
}

function notFunc(n1) {
  return !!n1
}

function norFunc(n1, n2) {
  return n1 && n2;
}

function nandFunc(n1, n2) {
  return notFunc(andFunc(n1, n2));
}

function addNumAction() {
  var n1 = document.getElementById("num1").value;
  var n2 = document.getElementById("num2").value;
  var n3 = document.getElementById("num3").value;
  var n4 = document.getElementById("num4").value;
  var n5 = document.getElementById("num5").value;
  var n6 = document.getElementById("num6").value;
  var b1 = new Boolean("false");
  var b2 = new Boolean("false");
  var b3 = new Boolean("false");
  var b4 = new Boolean("false");
  var b5 = new Boolean("false");
  var b6 = new Boolean("false");
  if (n1 == "1") {
    b1 = true;
  }
  if (n2 == "1") {
    b2 = true;
  }
  if (n3 == "1") {
    b3 = true;
  }
  if (n4 == "1") {
    b4 = true;
  }
  if (n5 == "1") {
    b5 = true;
  }
  if (n6 == "1") {
    b6 = true;
  }
  console.log(orFunc(andFunc(b4, notFunc(nandFunc(b3, b5)), norFunc(b6, norFunc(b1, nandFunc(b3, b2))))));
  var o1 = orFunc(andFunc(b4, notFunc(nandFunc(b3, b5)), norFunc(b6, norFunc(b1, nandFunc(b3, b2)))));
  console.log(orFunc(andFunc(b6, nandFunc(b3, b5))));
  var o2 = orFunc(andFunc(b6, nandFunc(b3, b5)));
  document.getElementById('result1').innerHTML = o1;
  document.getElementById('result2').innerHTML = o2;
}
```

```css
/*USe flex to display containers and image across*/

.gate-map {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  display: flex;
}


/*Image size*/

.gate-map img {
  width: 500px;
  height: 400px;
}


/*Position the inputs relative to this container*/

.inputs {
  position: relative;
  /*Need to set this due to position absolute on all child elements*/
  min-width: 2em;
}

/*Set base styling for inputs*/
.inputs input {
  /*Make blokc elements*/
  display: block;
  width: 2em;
  /*So they can be postioned in relation to parent*/
  position: absolute;
}

/*Demonstraring using padding over postion*/
.outputs {
  padding-top: 124px;
}

#result2 {
  margin-top: 102px;
}

/*Vertiacal lay position of inputs*/
#num1 {
  top: 66px;
}

#num2 {
  top: 100px;
}

#num3 {
  top: 123px;
}

#num4 {
  top: 158px;
}

#num5 {
  top: 260px;
}

#num6 {
  top: 308px;
}
```

```html
<h1>Logic Gates</h1>
<div class="gate-map">
  <div class="inputs">
    <input type="number" id="num1" min="0" max="1">
    <input type="number" id="num2" min="0" max="1">
    <input type="number" id="num3" min="0" max="1">
    <input type="number" id="num4" min="0" max="1">
    <input type="number" id="num5" min="0" max="1">
    <input type="number" id="num6" min="0" max="1">
  </div>

  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/XqZdP.png" />
  <div class="outputs">
    <div id="result1">?</div>
    <div id="result2">?</div>
  </div>


</div>
<button type="button" onclick="addNumAction()">
    GO
  </button>
```

Comment: hey there, thanks so much for helping out! this seems to make sense. it looks perfekt in the "run code snippet" option, however, when i try it out in my project is displays it differently. is there anything i need to consider ? this perplexes me a lot

Comment: USe the developer tools in your browser (often f12) to inspect the elements , see if there are any styles being overridden.